# max([column])where name = (each unique name in the name column) for each year in R

Tags: r

I am using the baby names data in R for practice.

```
total_n <-babynames %>% 
    mutate(name_gender = paste(name,sex))%>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(total_n = sum(n, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(total_n)

bn <- inner_join(babynames,total_n,by = "year")

df <- bn%>%
    mutate(pct_of_names = n/total_n)%>%
    group_by(name, year)%>%
    summarise(pct =sum(pct_of_names))
```

The dataframe output looked like this:

[image]

For each name, there's all the years, and the related pct for that year. I am stuck with getting the year with the highest pct for each name. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, once you know where the `babynames` data comes from. You had everything needed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(babynames)

total_n <-babynames %>% 
    mutate(name_gender = paste(name,sex))%>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(total_n = sum(n, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(total_n)

bn <- inner_join(babynames,total_n,by = "year")

df <- bn%>%
    mutate(pct_of_names = n/total_n)%>%
    group_by(name, year)%>%
    summarise(pct =sum(pct_of_names))
```

You were missing this final step:

```
df %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    filter(pct == max(pct))

# A tibble: 95,025 x 3
# Groups:   name [95,025]
        name  year          pct
       <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     Aaban  2014 4.338256e-06
 2     Aabha  2014 2.440269e-06
 3     Aabid  2003 1.316094e-06
 4 Aabriella  2015 1.363073e-06
 5      Aada  2015 1.363073e-06
 6     Aadam  2015 5.997520e-06
 7     Aadan  2009 6.031433e-06
 8   Aadarsh  2014 4.880538e-06
 9     Aaden  2009 3.335645e-04
10    Aadesh  2011 1.370356e-06
# ... with 95,015 more row
```

`group_by` and `filter` are your friends.

Comment: omg, can't believe it's that simple, I was thinking about looping. Thank you!